# A film featuring orcs, humans, and portals

Tags: story-identification, movie

A few months ago I watched a film, that featured orcs and begins with an orc opening a portal to another world. And it also featured a female orc character. What I didn't remember was the name and overall plot of that film.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Did you do a search before asking here? I searched "film with orcs and humans" and the first page of results is mostly Warcraft. (Yes I understand results can differ, but curious if this didn't show up in researching the question)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is [Warcraft: The Beginning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warcraft_(film)).

> The film follows Anduin Lothar of Stormwind and Durotan of the Frostwolf clan as heroes set on opposite sides of a growing war, as the warlock Gul'dan leads the Horde to invade Azeroth using a magic portal. Together, a few human heroes and dissenting Orcs must attempt to stop the true evil behind this war and restore peace.

Answer (score 11):

This could be [Orc Wars](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2333508/) AKA "Dragonfyre"

> A battle-weary ex-Special Forces Operative buys a ranch in remote American West to flee from the world, and encounters a strange series of trespassers, including a beautiful elf princess and a Native American mystic and Orcs. When the Orcs invade his property, John must give up his isolation to become a hero, before the Orcs unleash their dragon god on our world.

Orc Wars starts with the elf princess and some companions running from orcs who are trying to kill them.  They escape into a cave which has a portal to Earth.  When they arrive, still being chased, the hero gets to demonstrate that guns are stronger than orcs.

Comment: BTW, "Orc Wars" was the movie I was originally thinking of (I've seen it) but when I googled it, it came up with "Orcs!", which is a different movie (and I haven't seen it).   Both seem like possible matches.

Comment: Looks like neither movie is correct.  Still, my answers may be useful pointers for a future question about the fascinating genre of Orc-related movies that aren't either Warcraft-related or LOTR/The Hobbit.

Comment: Funnily enough, Orcs! and Dragonfyre were written by the same people; Jason Faller and Kynan Griffin.

Answer (score 7):

A potential candidate would be the movie [Bright (2017)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bright_(film)), which happens in a modern world with humans coexisting with orcs and some other species, along with magic.

> In an alternate present day, humans, orcs, elves and fairies have been coexisting since the beginning of time. Two police officers, one a human, the other an orc, embark on a routine night patrol that will alter the future of their world as they know it. Battling both their own personal differences as well as an onslaught of enemies, they must work together to protect a young female elf and a thought-to-be-forgotten relic, which, in the wrong hands, could destroy everything.

The premise also loosely sounds like something that could come out from [Shadowrun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadowrun), a tabletop role-playing game set in a near-future fictional universe with fantasy (i.e. "cyberpunk meets Tolkien" as some would sum it up), although there doesn't seem to be any movie based on that tabletop universe.

Comment: I don't recall a portal in *Bright* -- the orcs and other fantasy creature have been present throughout history (one of them was crucified ca. 2000 years ago, bringing about a fragile peace between the races).

Comment: @ZeissIkon To be honest, when I read the question title about "orcs and humans", that movie came to my mind even though I've never watched it (saw a Youtube advertisement about it while I was browsing). I thought I'd still share just in case.

Comment: Worth watching, IMO -- if only to see race played a different way (and Will Smith is excellent as usual).

Comment: Downvoted as it clearly doesn't match the portal part.

Answer (score 6):

This could be [Orcs!](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1524134/).

> When marauding orcs invade a US National Park, our collective fates lie in the hands of Ranger Cal Robertson and his side-kick, Volunteer Cadet Hobie, who must stop the wave of destruction before the whole world is overrun.